# Custom export pdf DataTables TableTools

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, datatables, tabletools

I tried to customize my pdf export to make a good look pdf export table but i'm with some problems.

Once i'm not good with AS programming i don't understand how i customize my export file.

The problem is:

I need customize the export of DataTable(TableTools) but when i modify the ZeroClipboard.as nothing happens. I need change the copy_xls_csv_pdf.swf too ? how I do that ? some one have some sample to make clear how I customize the export ? Datatable Forum don't help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some customization possibilities:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/pdf_message.html

Tells you how to add a message to the saved PDF using 'sPdfMessage', andhow to change the orientation (from portrait to landscape)of the output PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I have added image as pdf header and footer text in PDF. If you still need any help on this, then ping me.